# How to write a list literal that contains items conditionally?

Tags: list

Given a list literal `'(1 2 3)`

is it possible to conditionally include parts of the list?

eg:

```
'(1 2 3
  (when thing-is-true '(10 11 12)))
  4 5 6)
```

Which would result in

`'(1 2 3 4 5 6)` or `'(1 2 3 10 11 12 4 5 6)` dependent on `thing-is-true`.

---

Python for example supports:

```
[1, 2, 3, *([10, 11, 12] if thing_is_true else []), 4, 5, 6]
```

---

What is the most straightforward way to achieve this using a single expression, without first defining variables and them into a list?

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate because I'm not asking about adding items to a list. Rather, how to declare a list. Also notice the answer to this question is quite different.

Comment: Hmm, I guess there is minor difference in that the dup's answer doesn't mention `,@`, only `,`; but to my mind the answer in both cases is essentially: "you're looking for backquote".

Comment: I was aware of the feature (that it could be useful in this case), I just didn't know how to use it because I'm not that experienced in elisp.

Comment: I'm not aware of what you're aware of, I just talk about what's written in the question and vote accordingly.

Comment: Seems like a dup to me, regardless of a minor difference in what you're trying to do. The question is really about a misunderstanding, and the referenced duplicate Q&A covers that. (And the tags should include `quote` and not include `elisp`, IMO.)

Comment: The same feature solves both answers, but for a beginner its not obvious that this is possible. Said differently - I wouldn't have been able to get the answer given here from reading the other answer.

Comment: Now much more experienced in elisp and I still don't think this is a duplicate, the other question touches on similar areas but isn't about declaring a list literal. Just because the same language feature happens to work in both cases - doesn't make the question a duplicate IMHO. Especially as `(cons x y)` is a valid answer in that case which is related to quoting variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the macro [(elisp) Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html), e.g.,

```el
`(1 2 3 ,@(when nil '(10 11 12)) 4 5 6)
;; => (1 2 3 4 5 6)

`(1 2 3 ,@(when t '(10 11 12)) 4 5 6)
;; => (1 2 3 10 11 12 4 5 6)
```

if you expand the above macros, they are simply using `append`

```el
(append '(1 2 3) (when nil '(10 11 12)) '(4 5 6))
;; => (1 2 3 4 5 6)

(append '(1 2 3) (when t '(10 11 12)) '(4 5 6))
;; => (1 2 3 10 11 12 4 5 6)
```